# search for a string and get next few lines in another file as output file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have batch script which executes command and gets the output in *.log file.

Now I need to search for severity value which can be any of the following ie,

```
Caution
Critical
Repaired
```

If above values found in the log file then need to get next following 3 lines from that severity section in below format in a separate output file.

log file content :

```
    number=1
    severity=Informational
    date=12/01/2012
    time=07:56
    description=Maintenance note: sys log cleared through tool

    number=4
    severity=Critical
    date=05/13/2013
    time=18:03
    description=Network Adapter Link Down (Slot 0, Port 1)
```

In final_outputfile :

```
severity     date          time    Description
Critical     05/13/2016    18:03   Network Adapter Link Down (Slot 0, Port 0)
Repaired     06/21/2016    05:39   Network Adapter Link Down (Slot 0, Port 0)
```

so far I only able to create separate final_output file but getting some initial log filename as content.

I even need to get only those log file line which is dated lessthan a month/2 month back from current date. that will be next challenge.

Comment: woah this must be the 200th "find a string in a file using shell scripting" question this last few hours; is there some challenge going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, that are spaces in the input file. If not, adapt the code accordingly.

```
@echo off
setlocal
>out.log echo severity  date        time    Description
REM above there are a tabs (two of them between date and time)
set "wanted=Caution Critical Repaired"
(
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('type in.log^|findstr "severity= date= time= description="') do (
    if "%%a"=="    severity" echo\ 
    REM this is four SPACES above before severity
    <nul set /p "=%%b   "
    REM above there is a SPACE and a TAB after %%b 
  )
  echo/
)  >>out.log
type out.log |findstr /b "severity %wanted%"
```

Comment: I don't see where you filter out unwanted severity entries. Also, if space is to be included in DELIMS list, than it must be the very last character in the options string. Your comment implies you end with space tab instead of tab space.

Comment: @dbenham: I missed, that there are unwanted severities. Should be easy to fix (tomorrow - it's bed-time now). Are you sure about the space has to be the last character? "Space Tab" works for me, "Tab Space" does not.

Comment: Very sure - that has been the rule for a long time. A space is the token delimiter within the options string, unless it is the last character of the string.

Comment: @dbenham you are right; verified with some tests. I'm confused, because "SPC TAB" works for me, but "TAB SPC" doesn't. Anyway - noticed, neither the tab nor the space is really needed here. Code edited.

Comment: Many Thanks Stephan, your code works but I have morethan one input log file or have input log files from morethan one server, so everytime when I ran your code, it generate final output file for the last server log. I guess this "type in.log^" need to give full path where input log file resides. is that correct ? all the command executed log file get generated in "output" dir. my next question is : from your code, how can we extract only last 2 months data from current data.

Comment: calculating with dates is - well, it's possible with pure batch, but it isn't fun. Better look for an embedded powershell, java  or vba solution. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcmd%5D+get+yesterdays+date) for some possible solutions. The `MM/DD/YYY` format also is not really helpful for comparison. For processing several files, use a surrounding `for %%f in (*.log) do ...`. You can name the outfilles something like `%%~nf-out.log`. Please ask a new question, once you have built a basic code skeleton.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I was able to use for loop and get the required final output for all the log files. wrt to date logic, guess I need think of having vba solution. Thanks Again for your valuable advice. Much Appreciated.